# RhinoMocks - mock a concrete type - run constructor

Tags: rhino-mocks

I've got the following line, attempting to create a mock of a concrete type:

```
AddPropPersonalCOI = MockRepository.GenerateMock<SomeType>(ObjectFactory.GetInstance<paramType1>(), ObjectFactory.GetInstance<paramType2>());

Assert.IsNotNull(AddPropPersonalCOI.view);
```

I've actually stepped into the constructor in question, watched it execute, watched the view property get assigned from the value passed into the constructor (which I verified were not null), and yet the assert fails.

And yes, view is `virtual`.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `view` is virtual, you'll need to set an expectation for it before you can use it. Rhino Mocks gives you `null` values when you call methods and properties in expectations mode.

Comment: Makes perfect sense now that I think about it.  Thanks!